# iPhone: Display iAd issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am successfully iAd integration in my app using http://bees4honey.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-add-iad-banner-in-iphoneipad-app/ but iAd is not display in my app for testing purpose and yesterday its display but today its not display.

I am tested iAd demo on iOS 4.2.1 and 5.0 but still same problem not display on device so please give me idea about issue.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand with iAd and the Google Ad words for Android is that it is possible that sometimes no add will be loaded, that's why the apple documentation on it states that the banner needs to be hidden when you receive no add from there server.

So what I think is happening, if you didn't change anything from Yesterday is that there was no add send because there was none to display. Remember the advertisers pay per click or per impression and the advertiser decides how much he is willing to pay and sets a budget limit,. Also the context in which the add is displayed also goes into the algorithm for deciding when an add needs to be displayed to keep it relevant to what the end user is currently viewing, that way the user has a higher chance of actually clicking on the link.